# How to add target blank in this woocommerce code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

find this code in the [business bloomber.](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-edit-external-product-image-url/) I want to add target blank attribute in this code can any help me?
function bbloomer_image_link_external_url( $html,

```
$post_thumbnail_id ) {
   global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) return $html;
   $url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
   $pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
   $html = preg_replace( $pattern, $url, $html);  
   return $html ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_replace`. just add the below line after `preg_replace`.

```
$html = str_replace('<a', '<a target="_blank" ', $html);
```

Complete code.

```
function bbloomer_image_link_external_url( $html, $post_thumbnail_id ) {
   global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) return $html;
   $url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
   $pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
   $html = preg_replace( $pattern, $url, $html );  
   $html = str_replace('<a', '<a target="_blank" ', $html);
   return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'bbloomer_image_link_external_url', 100, 2 );
```

Tested and works.

[image]